# Как работает этот цикл?

Tags: javascript, циклы, операторы

Вот мой цикл.

```js
for (let x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {
    if (!x % 2 == 0) console.log(x); 
}
```

В результате выводятся такие значения – `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Не понимаю почему. Если, например взять тройку и подставить в if получится: `3 % 2 == 1`. Получается единица - это true, впоследствии true переводится в false → для тройки не должно срабатывать `console.log`. Почему срабатывает?

Comment: а не проще добавлять не единицу, а двойку к x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если расставить скобки в выражении `!x % 2 == 0` с учётом приоритетов операций, то будет:

```
((!x) % 2) == 0
```

И тогда условие в `if` будет вычисляться так:

```
x    !x        !x%2    !x%2==0
0    true      1       false
1    false     0       true
2    false     0       true
3    false     0       true
4    false     0       true
5    false     0       true
```

Если при написании сложного выражения есть сомнения в приоритете операторов, то можно расставить скобки. Также на developer.mozilla.org есть большая табличка с [приоритетами](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Answer (score 2):

Если взять единицу и подставить в иф, то получится не `1 % 2`, а `!1 % 2`. Любое число, кроме 0 это true. Соответственно not-любоечисло это false. false это 0. Остаток от деления 0 на 2 равен 0, условие выполнено - выводим число.

Возможно, вы хотели написать не `!x % 2 == 0`, а `!(x % 2) == 0`. Или `x % 2 == 0`, в зависимости от того, какие числа хотите вывести - четные или нечетные.

Answer (score 0):

Так хотели

```js
for (let x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) console.log(x); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {
    if (x % 2 === 0) console.log(x); 
}
```

Либо так для не парных чисел:

```js
for (let x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {
    if (x % 2 !== 0) console.log(x); 
}
```